# Transition and configuration of Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

In my lecture I have examples about 0 -> R (which means if it's 0, move Right) or 0 -> x, R (replace 0 with x and move Right) but I don't quite understand about the 0, 0 -> R expression. What is the configuration of Turing machine btw

Comment: A standard notation of transition of Turing machine can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition). Could you please show us more context (definitions/notations) in which $0,0 \to R$ is given in your lecture?

Comment: I've read the exercise again but there is no definition of the transition

Answer (score 1):

Notations vary, but "$0, 1 \rightarrow R$" can be short for "$0 \rightarrow R$ and $1 \rightarrow R$."

A configuration is a way of writing the current state of the TM, the symbols on the tape and the current position of the tape. Here's a common way to write a configuration: if the state is $q_0$, the tape has $101$, and the head is pointing at $0$, write $1q_001$.